# Write LINQ to parse aspx page using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, html-agility-pack

I have looked at the following and similar links on SO and google to parse aspx page using HTMLAgilityPack

[Parse html document using HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758792/parse-html-document-using-htmlagilitypack)

But I don't know how to write LINQ statement such that I could identify Button and Label Control Names in my aspx page.

Here is my aspx page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm4.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button on page4" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label on page 4"></asp:Label>
        <br />
                    <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="second button page 4" />

                        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="second button page 4" />



    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to write LINQ using HTML Agility pack such that I could list the following output:

**Controls on this page are Button1, Label1, Button2, Button3**

I am having trouble writing LINQ for parsing the aspx page. Please help.

Here is what I have written so far and its not working.

```
   HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

    htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;

    string filePath = @"C:\WebApplication1\webform4.aspx";


    htmlDoc.Load(filePath);

        htmlDoc.Load(filePath);


        var pagecontrols = from links in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                           where links.Attributes.Contains("runat")
                           select links.Attributes["ID"].Value;

        foreach (var pagecontrol in pagecontrols)
        {
            Response.Write(pagecontrol);
        }
```

Comment: What is set in `findItemPrices`?  What do you mean it's not working?

Comment: I am not able to access each control. Updated findItemPrices to pageControls

Comment: Your variable should have a collection of HTML elements not ASP.NET controls.  What are you trying to access?

Comment: I am trying to get listing of controls and need help with wriing LINQ

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner You can't get a list of "controls", you might be able to get a list of "Nodes" though. HtmlAgilityPack has absolutely no idea of how to parse asp.net-code, it will, however, happily parse html, or html-isch. You want to find "asp:Label"-nodes or "asp:Button"-nodes, or simply nodes with the attribute "runat=Server"

Comment: Hopefully the tool allows ":" in the node name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you need to do something like this:

```
var pagecontrols = from links in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                   where links.Attributes.Contains("runat")
                   select links.Attributes["ID"].Value;
```

Comment: I just tried your code and I do not get any thing in pageControls

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner: So have you accepted this answer but it doesn't work at all to use `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse an aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've already found the answer for this, but here is the solution which worked.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");
doc.LoadHtml(aspPage);
var elements = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div");  
var pageControls = from z in elements.ChildNodes
                     where z.Attributes.Contains("runat") //server controls
                     select z.Attributes["ID"].Value;
```