# Parse Table with LINQ and HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, linq, html-agility-pack

How can I parse HTML using LINQ on a webpage to get the `innerhtml` values from the table?

I am using the `HtmlAgilityPack` and would like to parse some values as good as possible.

the number you see(00000, 00001, 00002..), are unique numbers from the agents.

So maybe there is a way to use LINQ to parse those numbers and get the following values from `td's`

(Name, 123, state, and info) => 00000, John, 123, IDLE, coffee for each
so I can call them separately and work with them - maybe in a array?

```
</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>00000</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>John</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>123</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>IDLE</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>coffee</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>00001</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Lisa</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>123</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>IDLE</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>coffee</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>00002</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Mary</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>123</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>IDLE</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>coffee</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR ALIGN=RIGHT>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>00003</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Tim</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=CENTER>123</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>IDLE</TD>
        <TD ALIGN=LEFT>coffee</TD>
    </TR>
....
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's an answer with an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7758792/205233

Answer (score 1):

This seems a lot like a "please give me the code I need question", which I seriously dislike. Have a look at the following and make sure you understand it:

```
var doc = ... // Load the document
var trs = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("TR"); // Give you all the TRs
foreach (var tr in trs)
{
  var tds = tr.Descendants("TD").ToArray(); // Get all the TDs
  // Turn them into our datastructure
  var data = new {
             Name  = tds[1].InnerText,
             Number = tds[2].InnerText,
             State = tds[3].InnerText,
             Info  = tds[4].InnerText,
             };
  // Do something with data
}
```

Doing it with LINQ only:

```
var data = from tr in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("TR")
           let tds = tr.Descendants("TD").ToArray()
           select new {
             Name  = tds[1].InnerText,
             Number = tds[2].InnerText,
             State = tds[3].InnerText,
             Info  = tds[4].InnerText,
             };
```

Answer (score 0):

@flindeberg makes a perfectly reasonable answer (+1 to he/she), you could avoid the `ToArray` like this.

```
private class Row
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
var mappings = new Action<string, Row>[]
{
    (value, row) => row.Name = value,
    (value, row) => row.Number = int.Parse(value),
    (value, row) => row.State = value,
    (value, row) => row.Info = value
};

var doc = ... // Load the document
var trs = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("TR"); // Give you all the TRs
foreach (var tr in trs)
{
  var row = new Row();
  tr.Descendants("TD").Zip(mappings, (td, map) =>
  {
      map(td.InnerText, row);
      return true;
  });

  // You now have a populated row.
}
```